# How to remove email id & website box in wordpress comment

Tags: comments

We want to remove email id and website fields in the comments box of WordPress.

Do let me know the process or code of it.

Thanks in advance

Sample code of the webpage

```
<div class="post-info"><div class="meta-info"> <span class="posted"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i><time class="entry-date published" datetime="2017-06-19T15:02:41+00:00">June 19, 2017</time><time class="updated" datetime="2017-07-13T01:57:07+00:00">July 13, 2017</time></span><span class="comments"><i class="fa fa-comments"></i>0</span></div></div><div class="widget-post-excerpt"> 1213 RAZOLU-KPHB 20:45 → 03:20 Duration: 6 hrs SUPER LUXURY(Non-AC, 2 +&nbsp;&hellip;</div></div></div></li></ul></div><div id="commentsAdd"><div id="respond" class="comment-respond"><h3 id="reply-title" class="comment-reply-title">Add a Comment <small><a rel="nofollow" id="cancel-comment-reply-link" href="/ksrtc/hyderabad-bangalore/#respond" style="display:none;">Cancel reply</a></small></h3><form action="http://www.bustimings.in/wp-comments-post.php" method="post" id="commentform" class="comment-form" novalidate><p class="comment-notes"><span id="email-notes">Your email address will not be published.</span> Required fields are marked <span class="required">*</span></p><p class="comment-form-comment"><textarea id="comment" name="comment" cols="45" rows="8" aria-required="true"></textarea></p><p class="comment-form-author"><label style="display:none" for="author">Name<span class="required"></span></label><input id="author" name="author" type="text" placeholder="Name" value="swathi" size="30" /></p><p class="comment-form-email"><label style="display:none" for="email">Email<span class="required"></span></label><input id="email" name="email" type="text" placeholder="Email" value="saadhiyarao@gmail.com" size="30" /></p><p class="comment-form-url"><label style="display:none" for="url">Website</label><input id="url" name="url" type="text" placeholder="Website" value="" size="30" /></p><p class="form-submit"><input name="submit" type="submit" id="submit" class="submit" value="Add Comment" /> <input type='hidden' name='comment_post_ID' value='22' id='comment_post_ID' /> <input type='hidden' name='comment_parent' id='comment_parent' value='0' /></p></form></div></div> </main></div><div id="secondary" class="widget-area" role="complementary">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do by adding few lines of code in functions.php or using Disable Comment plugin.

But adding few lines of code would be great.

Steps:

1. Go to Editor > Open functions.php file.
2. Scroll down to the end of file and add lines of code given below

> ```
> function comments_custom_settings($fields) { 
>     unset($fields['url']);
>     unset($fields['email']);
>     return $fields;
> }
> add_filter('comment_form_default_fields','comments_custom_settings');
> ```

3. Save it and check.

I hope this answer helps you!